# Sturdy laptops for every day use (not ruggerized)

Tags: laptop

I'm a heavy laptop users, who takes her laptop everywhere everyday. That means, loads of little bumps, some drops of a drink are not avoidable. Children could lay their little dirty fingers on it or drop it, but mostly they are well-behaved.

I don't think I'll need to go so far as to buying a ruggerized laptop. I don't work in a mine or something like that.

My present computer is an Asus B-Series, and I am happy with it lasting for 7+ years.

I was thinking about something like Lenovo Thinkpad T-series or another Asus, but I'm want to contemplate all options.

Is this MIL-SPECS of Lenovo a reliable measure of sturdiness? If yes, what other laptops meet it?

In summary, I need resilient, battery 8+ hours, and a good keyboard, 14'' screen. Since I will last, it could be above $1,000. I also would like it to last more than 5+ years. Maybe I'll be exchanging the battery every couple of years. Performance is not a big issue. No need for multimedia, fancy games.

No Macs, don't care about thin, pretty, lots of colors.